# Rails 5.1, Rails 6.1.3 recaptcha v3 gem integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, recaptcha-v3

I found this doc to integrate rails gem recaptcha3 with device registration.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

So ... I add this to register form for device:

```
<%= recaptcha_v3(action: 'signup') %>
```

Then add this to controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any 
  actions you want to protect.

  private

  def check_captcha
    return if !verify_recaptcha # verify_recaptcha(action: 'signup') for v3

    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides reCAPTCHA
    set_minimum_password_length

    respond_with_navigational(resource) do
       flash.discard(:recaptcha_error) # We need to discard flash to avoid showing it 
       on the next page reload
       render :new
    end
  end
 end
```

Then I check gem documentation and add:

```
# config/initializers/recaptcha.rb
  Recaptcha.configure do |config|
     config.site_key  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     config.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

  # Uncomment the following line if you are using a proxy server:
  # config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'

  # Uncomment the following lines if you are using the Enterprise API:
  # config.enterprise = true
  # config.enterprise_api_key = 'AIzvFyE3TU-g4K_Kozr9F1smEzZSGBVOfLKyupA'
  # config.enterprise_project_id = 'my-project'
end
```

And what now? recaptcha is invisible because in V3 version it only save some scores. Does it work yet?

I do not find any tutorial or help for recaptcha v3 for device / rails.

Maybe someone do it already ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used it in the rails 6 app with devise
check this code https://github.com/Shaher-11/udzilla/commit/8220527e79eb49fa045fe1d7d1593031524de5a0